# Creating dialog windows

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a dialog window where I ask for a persons name with the format: Lastname, Surname

I'm then trying to show *just* the surname name in a new dialog window with the format: `Hello! SURNAME!`

This is my code so far:

```
import javax.swing.*; 

  public class Surname {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {

    String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Write your name: Lastname, surname ");

    int i, j;
    i = a.lastIndexOf(???);   
    j = a.indexOf(',' + 1);         

    a = a.substring(i, j);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello! " + a.toUpperCase());  }}
```

Comment: Your "substring" indexes are obviously wrong. `j` should probably be the end of the string (i.e. `.length`). Maybe you should take a look at [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the surname by splitting the string by ", ".

For example

```
String surname = "Novovic, Felix".split(", ")[0];
```

Since we are accessing an array here which size is fully determined by the input of the user, i.e. the user inputs "Novovic, Felix, Hello, World" you should reassure that the input is in the correct format before you access the array.

For example, by checking that the array length = 2

Answer (score 2):

Your substring is not correct, for the start you'll need the index of the comma, for the end simply the length of the string:

```
int i, j;
i = a.indexOf(',') + 2;
j = a.length();

a = a.substring(i, j);
```

Comment: This isn't quite correct. You need to do `i = a.indexOf(',') + 2;` otherwise the comma and space are included in the final string.

Comment: You're right, I thought the comma was in the original message which is why I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) this will do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Write your name: Lastname, surname ");
    String[] nameParts = a.split(",");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello! " + nameParts[1].trim().toUpperCase());  
}
```

... but you would probably want to add some more error handling. So this is only a bare bone example

Comment: This yields the lastname, he wanted the surname.

Comment: @TheCodingWombat Indeed... without arguing over what is the actual difference between those two (where I live there is none) I will amend the answer.

Comment: As far as I know there is no difference except maybe semantics. I just know what details the asker supplied us and he wanted the info after the comma (what he labeled as surname).